# Long entry and exit working independently to short entry in Pine script Strategy testing

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, back-testing

Is there any way that Long entry and exit works independently in Pine Script strategy?

Below is the example where I entered Long on 14-08-2019 and it exits as soon as the short signal arrived.

[image]